# Error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list<int>' and 'int')|

Tags: c++, merge, stl

I'm trying to take an even integer array and odd integer list, and then try to merge them in a vector, using the **merge** algorithm available in STL of C++. The task requires specifically to use the **merge** algorithm, and I'm getting stuck in error at **line 43** , right of which I've commented that that's the error point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void display(list<int>&l){
    list<int>::iterator p;
    for(p=l.begin();p!=l.end();++p){
        cout<<*p<<", ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
void display(int arr[6]){
     for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
     }
     cout<<"\n";
}
int main()
{
    int inp;
    int even_arr[6];
    list<int> odd_list(6);
    cout<<"Enter even numbers: ";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        cin>>even_arr[i];
    }
    display(even_arr);
    list<int>::iterator p;
    cout<<"\nEnter odd numbers: ";
    for(p=odd_list.begin();p!=odd_list.end();++p){
        cin>>inp;
        *p = inp;
    }
    display(odd_list);

    vector<int> vec1(12);
    list<int>::iterator itr=odd_list.begin();
    int *ptr=even_arr;
    merge(even_arr,even_arr+6,odd_list,odd_list+6,vec1);   //ERROR LINE

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is about `odd_list+6`. This may work for arrays but not for `std::list`. Try instead `odd_list.begin()` and `odd_list.end()`.

Comment: Upon correcting as mentioned by @Scheff ,the stl_algo.h file opens up pointing to line 4880 and showing " stl_algo.h|4880|error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::vector<int>')| "

Comment: Similar issue: Here, you need an [inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) - an insert functor with an iterator facade. I recommend to make `vec1` empty (instead of `vec1(12)`) and use a [std::back_inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). If you are concerned about the unnecessary re-allocations (while knowing the required size beforehand) you can pre-allocate with `vec1.reserve(12);`. This does the allocation but keeps the vector `vec1` still empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, using back_inserter(vec1) instead of vec1 in merge helped! @Scheff I guess there is no option for accepting a comment as an answer, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add something to a `std::list` like you can do with arrays. Also it's better to be explicit about iterators and use `std::end` to get the past-the-end-iterator, since you want to use the whole array anyway.

Also `std::merge()` expects iterators but the last parameter is `vec1`, which is a `std::vector`. The correct version would be:

```
merge(begin(even_arr), end(even_arr),
      begin(odd_list), end(odd_list),
      begin(vec1));
```

I omitted `std::` to improve readability.

Use of `std::begin` over `odd_list.begin()` (and similar) is debatable and up to personal preference.